# How to trim a String by bytes?

Tags: java, char, byte, trim

I have got a UTF-8 text and I want trim / truncate it by bytes so that a I get
a new String of a costumed length of Bytes.

```
public static String trimByBytes(String text, int longitudBytes) throws Exception {

    byte bytes_text[] = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int negativeBytes = 0;

    byte byte_trimmed[] = new byte[longitudBytes];
    if (byte_trimmed.length <= bytes_text.length) {
          //copy  array manually and count negativeBytes
        for (int i = 0; i < byte_trimmed.length; i++) {
            byte_trimmed[i] = bytes_text[i];
            if (byte_trimmed[i] < 0) {

                negativeBytes++;
            }
        }
         //if negativeBytes are odd
        if (negativeBytes % 2 != 0 && byte_trimmed[byte_trimmed.length - 1] < 0) {
            byte_trimmed[byte_trimmed.length - 1] = 0;//delete last

        }
    }else{
      for (int i = 0; i < bytes_text.length; i++) {
            byte_trimmed[i] = bytes_text[i];
        }

    }
    return new String(byte_trimmed);
}
```

}

e.g.

- nomenclature: String trimByBytes(String str, int lengthOfBytes);
  trimByBytes(Gómez ,1)
- Gómez is 6 bytes length  (but 5 chars length)
- Gómez trimmed at 3 is Gó ok Gómez trimmed at 2 is G� but I want G
  (remove odd character)
- Gómez trimmed at 1 is G ok Gómez trimmed at 8 is G Gómez

Comment: this is my approach, more solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an explicit [CharsetDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html), and set [CodingErrorAction.IGNORE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#IGNORE) on it.

Since a CharsetDecoder works with ByteBuffers, applying the length limit is as easy as calling the ByteBuffer’s [limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit%28int%29) method:

```
String trimByBytes(String str, int lengthOfBytes) {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

    if (lengthOfBytes < buffer.limit()) {
        buffer.limit(lengthOfBytes);
    }

    CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);

    try {
        return decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        // We will never get here.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```